# How to Submit Form with data plus ID in PHP

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

I want to Submit a form to another page through post action it takes all the data in array `$_POST` but what i want is to also be able to send `ID` of the current page to the new page which is not in the `$_Post` array do anyone know how can I do it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two ways to do that:-**

**What i will favor:-**

**1. Create an hidden field in your `POST` form and send data in `POST`. More secure and good:-**

```
<input type="hidden" name="pageID" id="pageID" value="<?php echo $pageID; ?>" />
```

**2. What i will not favor create a form like below:-**

```
<form action ="abc.php/?id = $id" method = "POST">
```

**here you need to check `$id` must have some value.**

**Note:-A much better approach in second case is encrypt the id and send it in query string and then decrypt it to original value.**

Comment: I Knew about the first option but for some reason I needed the second option gonna use that. Any reason you won't favor it ??

Comment: Any time any information in query string will shown to other, that may become security issue, Also if you want to go with second option then a much better approach is encrypt the id and send it in query string and then decrypt it to original value.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hidden input.

If you have your URL like :

> http://URL/?ID=#

then use:

```
$pageID = $_GET['ID'];

<input type="hidden" name="pageID" id="pageID" value="<?php echo $pageID; ?>" />
```

If you get your id another way just make sure the value is filled with that id.